# Combining URL paths

Tags: java, url

I have website address:

```
http://mywebsite.com/path/
```

and two integer variables: year and month.

```
int year = 2015;
int month = 10;
```

I want to create address:

```
http://mywebsite.com/path/year/month
```

for example:

```
http://mywebsite.com/path/2015/10
```

so I tried:

```
URL url = new URL(new URL(new URL(filmwebURL), Integer.toString(year)), Integer.toString(month));
```

but as a result I get:

```
http://mywebsite.com/path/month

http://mywebsite.com/path/10
```

what can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just manually concatenate the values.

```
URL url = new URL(filmwebURL + "/" + year + "/" + month);
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought there is something from URL class that I shoud use but it looks like the simplest answer is the best in this case.